# Change LineString style for leaflet map with R shiny

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny, geojson

I have a leaflet map in R with a lot of LineStrings in it. The lines default to blue, with a certain thickness. I want to change the line color and have the thickness depend on a weight variable. I create the map by reading a geojson file. Adding a "style" section directly to each linestring feature in the geojson isn't working. Here is my R code for the map:

```
colchoice = "red"
ptl_str = paste("#! function(feature, latlng){
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
    radius: feature.properties.radius || 5,
    fillColor: feature.properties.fillColor || '", colchoice, "',    
    color: '#000',
    weight: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
    })
    } !#", sep="")

m <- Leaflet$new()
m$setView(c(38.892682, -77.031681), zoom = 12)
m$geoJson(geojson, 
      onEachFeature = "#! function(feature, layer){
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popup)
      } !#",        
      pointToLayer = ptl_str)
m
```

This successfully formats points on the map into dots. But now I want to format the lines differently too. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Upfront: i know nothing about R and not able to test what i'm saying, but i know my way around Leaflet in Javascript and can tell you how i would go about accomplishing that in JS, so you can translate it to R:

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.Polyline) {
            layer.setStyle({
                'color': feature.properties.color
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/g4juen?p=preview

Comment: Thanks iH8! I'll try to translate from this, but the part about getting it into R is really what is vexing me.